# Multiple fetches with different timeouts - Vanilla JS (no nesting)

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have data coming from two APIs and each has a different request limit (and also what makes sense for a fetch frequency). I managed to make one work, but having two overwrites the first one and only fetches the second request. How do I combine two fetch requests with different timeouts to make both work?

this is the fetch structure I'm working with currently:

```
function fecske() {      
       fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=true')
            .then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
            .then(function (data) { appendData(data); });    setTimeout(fecske, 2000); }; fecske()
    
   function appendData(data) { 
//applying stuff here to different divs
 }
```

nesting one into the other wont work as one has to request every 2-5 seconds the other one should request once an hour - so nesting the once an hour into the few seconds would call that as well too often (if I'm right?)

Comment: I only see a request to a single API, not two. Also, how are the two API requests related? Is it really necessary to coordinate them with each other? If so, what *kind* of coordination is neeeded? Can you only call B once the call to A is complete (e.g., you need information from A when calling B)? Or the other way around? Or...?

Comment: thats the question here, how do I have two work on the same page with different request rates - I havent figured that out.

they dont have to work with each other, two requests from two different APIs, they just both have to work on the same html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that the two API requests have to happen at different rates, and that they aren't related to each other — you don't need information from one of them to do the other or anything like that.

First, a caveat: Repeatedly polling like this is almost always an anti-pattern, and it's something that browsers are actively moving to throttle. [Here's an article by Jake Archibald about throttling in Chrome and, crucially, alternatives to polling available in modern browsers](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/).

But back to the polling. If they're really independent, you literally just keep them complete separate. You could do that by writing the same thing twice with different URLs and options and such...

```
function doRequestA() {
    fetch("https://example.com/request/A")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        // ...do something with `data`...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    })
    .finally(() => {
        if (shouldKeepDoingRequestA) {
            setTimeout(requestA, interval);
        }
    });
}

function doRequestB() {
    fetch("https://example.com/request/B")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        // ...do something with `data`...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    })
    .finally(() => {
        if (shouldKeepDoingRequestB) {
            setTimeout(requestB, interval);
        }
    });
}
```

...or (and this is what I would do) you could give yourself a utility function to do it; here's the latter:

```
// Utility function that gets JSON with appropriate HTTP check
function fetchJSON(...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}

// Utility functon for repeated JSON requests that you can cancel when needed
function startRepeatJSONRequest({url, options = undefined, callback, signal, interval = null}) {
    function doRequest() {
        fetchJSON(url, {...options, signal})
        .then(data => {
            if (!signal.aborted) {
                callback(data);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...handle/report error...
        })
        .finally(() => {
            if (!signal.aborted && interval !== null) {
                setTimeout(doRequest, interval);
            }
        });
    }
    doRequest();
}

// Repeated requests for API A
const controllerA = new AbortController();
startRepeatJSONRequest({
    url: "https://example.com/request/A",
    callback(data) {
        // ...use `data` here...
    },
    signal: controllerA.signal,
    interval: 3000, // or whatever
});

// Repeated requests for API B
const controllerB = new AbortController();
startRepeatJSONRequest({
    url: "https://example.com/request/A",
    callback(data) {
        // ...use `data` here...
    },
    signal: controllerB.signal,
    interval: 5000, // or whatever
});
```

Note the use of [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)/[`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) so you can cancel the process when you don't need it anymore.

---

In both of the above, note the check on `response.ok` in the first fulfillment handler on the `fetch` calls. This is to deal with what is (IMHO) a footgun in the `fetch` API: It only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors (like 404s or 500s). For those it fulfills its promise, but the `Response` object's `ok` property is `false` and the `status` has the HTTP status. I wrote this up [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic old blog.

Comment: Thanks T.J.! I've tried something like your first one - for some reason that didn't work (i changed the function name to be different) - the second one overwrote the first request, maybe i did something wrong. The second option looks promising, thanks for that, will try it out!
One qestion, in the meantime I managed to make it work with nesting the second in the first one, but I'm not sure that is smart to do - is that going to call the second one too often if the first one is called every 2 seconds? (the second one's timeout is set to something like 15 mins)

Comment: @bambadamm - I can't think of any reason the requests would interfere with each other when kept completely separate. I wouldn't nest them; they're independent of each other, best to keep them that way. :-)

Comment: yep, makes sense :) I've read the article quickly, I probably won't have the hidden page issue as its going to be a smart tv app - no browser tabs - I'm guessing that eliminates the problem? I'm new to tv app dev, but im not expecting too much from its built in browser - its probably years outdated

Comment: it probably eliminates the throttling problem, but not the problem the throttling is intended to solve: Polling is expensive in terms of data transfer. But if users are expecting that the app will be constantly transferring data while it's up... (I don't know what Smart TVs do when the app is running but not showing; *hopefully* they throttle, but...)

Comment: well, it should be expected by the users. Tried your second one, works like charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which function should I call manually for a refresh? (on changing currency with a button for example) (outside of this combined one)

Comment: fyi, just as I thought, tvs are living at least 5-10 years ago in technology, I had to go the down the polling route as the smarter combined way simply did not load at all on TVs